# looking for file extension filter for both desktop and Android java app

Tags: java, android

I need to create a filter that would filter files in a folder by extension. I prefer to create one filter that would combine several extensions and be case insensitive.

I am using FileNameExtensionFilter class from javax.swing

```
FileFilter filter = null;
filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Text file", "txt", "text");
```

which works fine on desktop but throws this on Android:

```
02-29 09:48:04.751: E/AndroidRuntime(25217): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter
```

Is there an alternative class that would work both on desktop and Android.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could browse the code yourself and create your own version. There aren't any swing dependencies apart from `FileNameExtensionFilter` itself and its superclass.

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/javax/swing/filechooser/FileNameExtensionFilter.java